# Reduce Border bottom length

Tags: html, css

[image: Updated one]Hi I want to know that whether can i reduce length of border bottom. I have a div and i have given border-bottom: 2px to that div i want to reduce the length of border. Is this possible.[image]

I have this nav-bar and i have given css to its div want to reduce length of border. How can i do that.

This is my html

```
               <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 welcome">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav-primary">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#one" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="li-text">Location</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#two" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-heartbeat" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="li-text">Heartbeats</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#three" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-power-off" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span class="li-text">Reboots</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#four" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-compress" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span class="li-text">Reconnects</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#five" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-battery-full" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span class="li-text">Charge</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
```

This is my CSS

```
        .welcome {
              border-bottom: 2px solid #bcbcbc;
              margin-left: 10px;
             }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the welcome class into the `ul` tag and it should do what you want :)

Comment: well then you have to add a couple of properties to you .welcome css. You could either use flexbox, or margin and width

Answer (score 1):

remove the **border-bottom** css from the class **welcome**
and use this;

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-nav-primary {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}
.welcome {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for set height and width for set length

```
.welcome{
width:1000px;
border-bottom:1px solid magenta; 
height:100px;   
}
```

Comment: No this will do it for div and i want for border bottom.